# PHP PDO array result is empty but var_dump returning the full result

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have the following PHP function:

```
public function getCad($conn,$gov)
{   
    try
    {
        //if($gov=='All')
        //{

        //}
        //else
        //{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM governorate 
            WHERE governorate_name=:gov 
            ORDER BY governorate_name ASC";
            $exec = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $exec->bindValue(':gov', $gov);
            $exec->execute();

            $result = $exec->fetch();
            return $result;
        //}
    }
    catch(PDOExcpetion $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The result is not returning any data.

When I use `var_dump($result);`, the data array is displayed:

```
public function getCad($conn,$gov)
{   
    try
    {
        //if($gov=='All')
        //{

        //}
        //else
        //{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM governorate 
            WHERE governorate_name=:gov 
            ORDER BY governorate_name ASC";
            $exec = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $exec->bindValue(':gov', $gov);
            $exec->execute();

            $result = $exec->fetch();var_dump($result);
            return $result;
        //}
    }
    catch(PDOExcpetion $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

At the first script, no errors displayed, and if I `var_dump($gov)`, the value exists.

The call function is:

```
<?php

require_once('../api.php');

$newApi = new api();
$conn = $newApi->connection();
$gov = 'Beirut';
$errorMsg = "Gov is not specified";
if(isset($gov))
{

    $res = $newApi->getCad($conn, $gov);
    return json_encode($res);
}
else
{
    return json_encode($errorMsg);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you show me how you call the function and use the data?

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question.

Comment: @KoenHollander done

Comment: is the call script ajax?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to use `echo` in your top-level script - `return` isn't going to do anything useful outside of a function body.

Comment: You have a typo here `PDOExcpetion`. Edit: This was edited. I made a mistake in my initial comment. But this still has a typo.

Comment: Shouldn't this `return json_encode($res);` be `echo json_encode($res);`

Comment: @iainn disagree - return in top-level, echo results in call (but maybe this is a matter of pref. ?)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs you are right. When I used echo in the call function, the result was clearly displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your calling script try

`echo json_encode($res);`

instead of

`return json_encode($res);`

Comment: Well, surprisingly, your solution was the answer.